# ArrayAdapter for generic objects

Tags: java, android, generics, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Is there any way to get an `ArrayAdapter` which could recieve any kind of object? Or maybe create multiple constructors?

Comment: But it's already generic, are you trying to mix objects? That defeats the purpose of generics in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. To not have to implement several arryadapters when you are using a lot of objects.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter <Object>a = new ArrayAdapter<Object> (context, android.R.id.text1, new ArrayList<Object> ());` to get rid of the Type casting warnings (bad), ***although*** I still don't recommend mixing Types. If all your objects have a common parent, you can parameterize for that parent. Paraming for Object is a sign that you are not designing your application properly.

Comment: And how would you manage to pass 15 objects to an adapter without making it generic nor creating 15 classes for each object?

Comment: Adapters are used to keep the data shown to the user. Usually, this is done with the same object since the list will have one "idea". Do those 15 objects have a common property so you can make a superclass and have *some* sort of type safety? What do those objects do?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe some of them, but not all of them. Anyway, I've  implemented a generic adapter because of your support. So... thanks, but, why did you say that it is not recommended? Is it dangerous for some reason?

Comment: It's dangerous since now you have no type safety. For example, If I made an `ArrayAdapter <Object>` and added a `String`, a `Double` and a `Custom` object. Sure, passing off to the Adapter will be ok since the ListView will only call `toString()` on each and display the result. But if now you want to get one of the Objects you are [increasing risk for compile time errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) since you have to be absolutely sure about what you're working with.